# Calling a superclass method from a subclass in python

Tags: python, call, subclass, static-methods, superclass

I was wondering if a subclass could call its parent static method, and tested it : it works like I hoped!

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def static(cls):
    print('act on '+cls.__name__)

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print('foo()')

>>> B.static()
act on B
```

I wanted to know if it had pitfalls to be aware of when using that technique ...

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are calling is the parent's `classmethod`, not a `staticmethod`.

Anyway, both of them are OK and common to be called with a subclass.

In case you override `A`'s `classmethod` in your `B`, you can still refer to `A.static` using `super(B, cls).static`.